# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nestedSortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

I am try to use nested sort plugin from https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable , but i keep getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nestedSortable is not a function
```

This is my head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

This is the body

```
    <ol class="sortable">
    <li><div>Some content</div></li>
    <li>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <ol>
            <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
            <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><div>Some content</div></li>
</ol>
```

Javascript code that i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
        handle: 'div',
        items: 'li',
            toleranceElement: '> div'
    });
});
```

Please help me

Comment: I'm not good with JQuery, But sometimes When I get this error in JS the problem is in the function.

Comment: Same code works in fiddle without any modifications, except for the scripts resources: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/785/ > Probably try with the cdn files instead of local files. Or just update the nestedSortable file.

Comment: Be careful when you include your plugins; before or after you include jquery. Sometimes this can be an issue.

Comment: Check your console to ensure the JavaScript files are both being loaded. It looks like the nestedSortable plugin may not be getting loaded.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers :) It works now after i fix the js path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested nestedSortable and this code work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>


  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script> 


      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
            handle: 'div',
            items: 'li',
            toleranceElement: '> div'
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div>
        <ol class="sortable">
          <li><div>Some content</div></li>
          <li>
            <div>Some content</div>
            <ol>
              <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
              <li><div>Some sub-item content</div></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li><div>Some content</div></li>
        </ol>

      </div>
    </body>
```

try putting this code in a file and execute it.  If it works dont use external links

download the css and js keep them in your project folder and include them from there

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the upgraded version of **nestedSortable**. Here is the updaed version of `nestedSortable`: https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable

Also you have not included jQuery-UI.js file in your file : `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` add this code before you include `jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js` file

Comment: He has included jquery-ui, it's in his example code.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the method does not exist on your jQuery object. This means the nestedSortable plugin has not loaded.

Refer to this line:

```
<script src="js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
```

Check that the address is correct, and that the JavaScript file exists in that location.

Answer (score 0):

update your script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the following github: [NESTEDSORTABLE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable/master/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js)